# Upload content to AWS S3 and serve the content via Cloudfront

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to upload static contents like image to AWS S3 and provide a link back so that image can be accessed through Cloudfront CDN (content delivery network). I am new to AWS and I read that s3 bucket is linked to CDN and I believe it's all configuration based. From java code I am able to upload to s3 and get the bucket based url back. How can I retrieve CDN url from java code for the same uploaded image. Could you please help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS S3 has to be manually linked to AWS CloudFront (Image attached). [image]

Once a Distribution is created, you can see a new domain mapped to the distribution. Using that domain name you should be able to access the CDN URL in your Java code.